# C sscanf to validate input format

Tags: c, scanf

I want to write a program which reads a line of input from the user, in the following format: `<Name>,<Age>,<City>`

- The Name can contain English letters, spaces and `-` only.
- The Age must be an integer between 18 to 120.
- The City must contain English letters and `-` only.

Each of them can be of size 49.
I want to store the information and print an informative error will be printed for bad input.

My code is the following:

```
    char str[150];
    char input[3][50] = { 0 };
    int num = 0;
    if (fgets(str, 150, stdin) != NULL) {
        num = sscanf(str, "%[a-zA-Z -],%[0-9],%[a-zA-Z-]", input[0], input[1], input[2]);
    }
    if (num < 3) {
        printf("ERROR\n");
    }
```

The problem is that an error will not be printed for an input such as `Name1$#,20,NY`, `Best,19,Rome123`, or `Best,100,Paris1$`, where the city is in wrong format (with trailing characters). There is any way to solve it using `sscanf`?

Comment: Note: the `%[...]` specifier is **NOT** a regular expression.

Comment: `char str[150];` is too short, you want minimum 49+1+49+1+49+1+1 (the 2nd last +1 is for newline, the last +1 is for string terminating `'\0'` char). Well, unless you take care of reading the newline outside of the code shown here.

Comment: @pmg: also, the use of ranges in the `%[…]` specifier is implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sscanf()` and character classes for your purpose but there are small problems with your format string:

- `A-Z` assumes ASCII encoding or at least an encoding where letters are contiguous.
- a trailing `-` has a special meaning, put the dash in first position to match a dash explicitly.
- there is no length prefix, so a name or city longer than 49 characters will overflow the destination array.

Rather than using `fgets()`, you should read the line mannually to detect overlong lines.

You can add an extra `%c` to check for extra characters at the end of the line. Storing the converted value is not required if you don't intend to use the field values, but you must convert the number to check if its value is in the requested range:

```
    char str[150];
    char name[50];
    char city[50];
    char agestr[4];
    size_t i;
    int c, age, pos, n;

    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++) {
        if (i < sizeof(str) - 1)
            str[i] = (char)c;
    }
    if (c == EOF && i == 0) {
        printf("end of file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (i >= sizeof(str)) {
        printf("line too long\n");
        return 0;
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    pos = 0;
    /* validate the name */
    if (sscanf(str + pos, "%49[-a-zA-Z ]%n", name, &n) != 1 || str[pos + n] != ',') {
        printf("invalid name\n");
        return 0;
    }
    pos += n + 1;
    /* validate the age */
    if (str[pos] == '0' || sscanf(str + pos, "%3[0-9]%n", agestr, &n) != 1 || str[pos + n] != ',') {
        printf("invalid age\n");
        return 0;
    }
    age = atoi(agestr);
    if (age < 18 || age > 120) {
        printf("age out of range: %d\n", age);
        return 0;
    }
    pos += n + 1;
    /* validate the city */
    if (sscanf(str + pos, "%49[-a-zA-Z]%n", city, &n) != 1 || str[pos + n] != '\0') {
        printf("invalid city\n");
        return 0;
    }
    /* Input was validated... proceed */
```

Comment: +1, but that conditional in the `if` statement is beautifully brutal, and adding proper error checking for `age` by using `strtol()` instead of `atoi()` would make it even worse.  IMO this is OK for some throwaway code, but it's not what I'd want to have in some code base just waiting to trip up some new maintainer in a few years.  "We need to add an address to the data..."

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I agree about the readability issue and might fix that, but regarding `atoi()`, there is no problem since the `agestr` has at most 3 digits from the `sscanf()` format string.

Comment: @chqrlie: that test will fail mysteriously if the newline is missing. Technically that's legit but it seems like `%n` is a better option here. (Check that character `n` is `\n` or `\0`; could later be extended by also allowing `,`)

Comment: @rici: the missing newline is more likely caused by a line too long than a missing newline at the end of the file. Accepting `'\n'` and `'\0'` and it is not sufficient.

Comment: @chqrlie: yes, you also have to check the value of `n`. Fortunately, that's not too difficult. (And this is why I prefer `getline` to `fgets`.)

Comment: @rici: rather than using `fgets()` or `getline()`, I updated the answer to read a full line, discarding excess length with an error. I do not store the newline in the buffer. The extra `%c` should fail conversion.

Comment: @N4D4V:  If you want to make the error messages more specific, you could make separate calls to `sscanf()` for each field and verify each field specifically.